# jQuery - getting text from attribute

Tags: jquery, pickadate

I'm using a plugin called pickadate and I'm trying to get the aria label text from the chosen date and apply it onto a div. Im able to retrieve the value once but if you click on another day the date in #date doesn't update?

http://jsfiddle.net/mg6fxqbe/

```
 var $elements = {
     datepicker: $('.js-datepicker'),
 };

 $elements.datepicker.pickadate();


 $('.picker__day').on('click', function () {
     var date = $(this).attr('aria-label');
     $('#date').empty().text(date);
 });
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the docs for the datepicker plugin you can use the `onSet` event to retrieve the current date that has been set.

> The onSet event is the only callback that is passed a context argument that provides details as to which properties are being “set”.
>
> Within scope of all six of these events, **this** refers to the picker.

```js
$('.js-datepicker').pickadate({
    onSet: function() {
        $('#date').text(this.$node.val());
    }
});
```

```css
#date{ font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; margin:20px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<input class="js-datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Select date" />
<div id="date"></div>
```

[Here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) you can find more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var $elements = {
     datepicker: $('.js-datepicker'),
 };

$elements.datepicker.pickadate();


 $('.picker__day').on('click', function (e) {
     $('#date').empty();
     var date = $(e.target).attr('aria-label');
     $("#date").html(date);
     return false;
 });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6fxqbe/4/)

Comment: Wanna comment on why you downvoted a working example?

Comment: Someone probably down voted, because if you read the docs for the datepicker plugin you will find a much easier solution without even adding a listener to the click event, which is obviously already present. There is an `onSet` event that fires whenever you set a new date.

Comment: Sorry only just noticed with the return false it stops the date going into the actual input?